# Expect: How to access variables and commands

Tags: bash, expect, spawn

I'm attempting to do a for loop so that i can read each file from the **ls** output inside my expect script.

```
/usr/bin/expect << 'EOF'
set timeout -1
spawn ssh root@server
expect { 
            "*assword: " 
       }
send "_t00rhs!\r"
expect { 
            "*]# " 
       }

send 'for item in "\$(ls)" do sort -k1 -n ${item}; done \r'
expect { 
            "*]# " 
       }
```

The output shows that it hasnt got the value for item.

```
]0;root@atddpvm13:~[?1034h[root@atddpvm13 ~]# can't read "item": no such 
variable
while executing
"send 'for item in "\$(ls)" do sort -k1 -n ${item}"
```

Comment: Why did you escape the `$` before running `ls` and _not_ for `item`?

Comment: If i escape both, i get this   ]0;root@server:~[?1034h[root@server~]# usage: send [args] string
    while executing
"send 'for item in "\$(ls)" do sort -k1 -n \${item}"

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 0):

From the expect side:

- single quotes have no special meaning in expect
- use braces for non-interpolating quoting
- however the `\r` sequence will not be interpreted in braces

So you get

```
send {for item in $(ls); do sort -k1 -n "$item"; done}
send "\r"
```

From the shell side

- [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [don't use `for` to iterate lines](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

You want

```
send "printf '%s\n' * | sort -k1 -n\r"
# or
send "ls -1v\r"
```